# Failing to update the new data entered by administrator

Tags: php, mysql

Look like everything is working fine with this code but in fact fails to update the database, Data are displayed correctly while fetching data but when i press update Button the data disappear but no update has been executed. It look fine to me but seems i am wrong.
This is a project for my professor so i don't care for the SQL injection and others.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="btnstyle.css">
  <title>Managament System</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>TU Chemnitz Student managament system</h1>

  <br>
  <a href="insert_form.html" class="myButton">ADD Person</a>
  <a href="insert_form.html" class="myButton">Edit Person</a>
  <a href="insert_form.html" class="myButton">Manage Boards</a>
  <a href="insert_form.html" class="myButton">Manage Departments</a>
  <a href="search_personel.html" class="myButton">Search N&S</a>
  <a href="three_search.html" class="myButton">Triple Search</a>
  <a href="mtable.php" class="myButton">Membership</a>

  <br>
  <br>

<?php 

// set database server access variables: 
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = ""; 
$pass = ""; 
$db = "";

// open connection 
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 

// select database 
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 

// create query 
$querys = "SELECT * FROM tblperson"; 



// execute query 
$result = mysql_query($querys) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 


echo "<table border=1 align=center>
<tr>
<th>Personal ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Deparment</th>
<th>Board</th>
<th>Marticulation Number</th>
<th>Reg Date</th>
<th>Action</th>

</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <?php
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['personid'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['personname'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['personsurname'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['persondepartment'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['personboard'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['martinumber'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'. $row['personregdate'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.'<a href="edit20.php?edit='.$row['personid'] . '"> EDIT </a> '.'</td>';

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the edit file which seems to problematic.

```
<?php 

include_once('coneksioni.php');

if(isset($_GET['edit']))
{
        $personid = $_GET['edit'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblperson WHERE personid='$personid'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
}
        if(isset($_POST['newpersonname']))
        {
            $newpersonname = $_POST['newpersonname'];
            $personid = $_POST['personid'];
            $sql = "UPDATE tblperson SET personname = '$newpersonname' WHERE personid = '$personid'";
            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Cant be updated");
            echo "< meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=home.php'>";
        }
?>


  <form action="edit20.php" method="POST">
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="newpersonname" value="<?php echo $row[1];?>" maxlength="30" size="13"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="personsurname" value="<?php echo $row[2];?>" maxlength="30" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td>
            <select name='persondepartment'>
            <option>Production</option>
            <option>Sales</option>
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Board</td>
        <td>
            <select name='personboard'>
            <option>Evaluation</option>
            <option>Executive</option>
            <option>Research</option>
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Marticulation Number</td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="martinumber" maxlength="60" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Date of Registration</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="personregdate" maxlength="7" size="7"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value=" Update"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: This is not a mysqli code!!

Comment: what does `$_GET['edit'];` return? Is this correct? Try debugging it .. dont do the meta command yet untill you get it right. You probably get an error thrown without you realizing it. Maybe you dont realize it, but when you refresh a page your edit value will be gone.

Comment: '<a href="edit20.php?edit='.$row['personid'] . '">'   $_GET['edit']; takes the correct id from where i clicked and displays it in the edit form.

Comment: I have checked the database nothing is changed,  I have no idea an no errors appear.  @Saty , Yes this is not Mysqli just mysql for now.

Comment: I would suggest keep `$personid` in one hidden field, so that when you execute the update query inside `POST` condition, instead of fetching value from $_GET, retrieve it from hidden field name.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for personid when the Update button is pressed on the form in edit20.php but that value has never been set so it will be empty and the update will fail.

After

```
  <form action="edit20.php" method="POST">
```

add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="personid" value="<?php echo $personid; ?>">
```

Comment: Dont forget that he needs to change the Get value to post value in his processing stage.

Comment: He does not need to do that in this case. The GET covers entry to the page from the other page, where an ID is selected, while the POST value he needs will be delivered in the form via the hidden field. If he changes the GET it will not work and break things.

Comment: Yea i figured that, i missed the part that he already posted that id. It just didnt excist in his code

Answer (score 0):

On edit page seem your confusing the same variable with different values. If you state $personid variable to contain the edit value from get, then just re-use the variable don't assign new value. On this line you assign new value :

```
$personid = $_POST['personid'];
```

Don't assign new value since it has the initial value already to use just set the variable global for usage

```
$personid = $_GET['edit'];
```

Or else create a hidden element and pass edit value into it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add name attribute for your update button

```
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="update" value=" Update"></td>
```

and chk whether the update button set or reset as in the place of

```
 if(isset($_POST['newpersonname'])) // change text 'newpersonname' as 'update'
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a variable that doesn't excist:

```
<?php 

include_once('coneksioni.php');

if(isset($_GET['edit']))
{
        $personid = $_GET['edit'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblperson WHERE personid='$personid'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
}
if(isset($_POST['newpersonname']))
{
            $newpersonname = $_POST['newpersonname'];
            $personid = $_POST['personid']; // this doesn't excist
            $sql = "UPDATE tblperson SET personname = '$newpersonname' WHERE personid = '$personid'";
            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Cant be updated");
            echo "< meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=home.php'>";
        }
?>
```

`$personid = $_POST['personid'];` doesn't excist in your code. Its simply a piece of code you put in there to probably proces, but forgot to define the variable in the code. Place the following in your form.

`<input type="hidden" name="personid" value="<?php echo $_GET['edit']; ?>">`

You only use this just once because you send the form back after proces to your home, hence it wont be used anymore. You can also use the avariable you defined as `$personid;` on that position.

If that fails, something maybe wrong in your query. Try to echo out the query (remove qucikly the meta command) by simply just do `echo $sql` after you do the sql query. 9 out of 10 times, it's a typo.